# Modal is disappearing when click on the input button inside it (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following Modal element:

```
import { useState } from "react";

import { MouseEvent, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import CloseIcon from "../assets/close-icon.svg";
import { ImagesIcon } from ".";

export const DialogModalTester = () => {
    const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);

    const onProceed = () => {
        console.log("Proceed clicked");
    };

    // Image
    function displayFile(file: any) {
        let fileType = file.type;
        let validExtensions = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"];
        if (validExtensions.includes(fileType)) {
            console.log("Approved");
            let img = "";
            dragAreaRef.current.innerHTML = img;
        } else {
            // add warning info
            dragAreaRef.current.classList.remove("active");
        }
    }

    let onDragOver = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dragAndDropRef.current.textContent = "Release to Upload";
        dragAreaRef.current.classList.add("active");
    };

    let onDragLeave = (event: any) => {
        dragAndDropRef.current.textContent = "Drag & Drop";
        dragAreaRef.current.classList.remove("active");
    };

    let onDrop = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let file;
        file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
        console.log(file);
        displayFile(file);
    };

    let dragAreaRef = useRef<any>(null);
    let dragAndDropRef = useRef<any>(null);
    let browseInputRef = useRef<any>(null);

    let inputChange = () => {
        let file = browseInputRef.current.files[0];
        dragAreaRef.current.classList.add("active");
        displayFile(file);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpened(true)}>Open "dialog" modal</button>

            <DialogModal isOpened={isOpened} onClose={() => setIsOpened(false)}>
                <div id="image-modal">
                    <div className="upload-container">
                        <div className="header">
                            <h1>Image</h1>
                            <button className="close-btn" onClick={() => setIsOpened(false)}>
                                <img src={CloseIcon}></img>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            className="drag-area"
                            ref={dragAreaRef}
                            onDragOver={onDragOver}
                            onDragLeave={onDragLeave}
                            onDrop={onDrop}
                        >
                            <div className="icon">
                                <ImagesIcon />
                            </div>

                            <span ref={dragAndDropRef} className="drag-and-drop">
                                Drag & Drop{" "}
                            </span>
                            <span className="browse">
                                or{" "}
                                <span
                                    onClick={() => browseInputRef.current.click()}
                                    className="browse-btn"
                                >
                                    browse
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <input ref={browseInputRef} type="file" hidden></input>
                            <span className="support">Supports: JPEG, JPG, PNG</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </DialogModal>
        </div>
    );
};

const isClickInsideRectangle = (e: MouseEvent, element: HTMLElement) => {
    const r = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        e.clientX > r.left &&
        e.clientX < r.right &&
        e.clientY > r.top &&
        e.clientY < r.bottom
    );
};

type Props = {
    isOpened: boolean;
    onClose: () => void;
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

const DialogModal = ({ isOpened, onClose, children }: Props) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isOpened) {
            ref.current?.showModal();
            document.body.classList.add("modal-open"); // prevent bg scroll
        } else {
            ref.current?.close();
            document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
        }
    }, [isOpened]);

    return (
        <div
            className="modal-overlay"
            onClick={(e) =>
                ref.current && !isClickInsideRectangle(e, ref.current) && onClose()
            }
        >
            <dialog className="modal-dialog" ref={ref} onCancel={onClose}>
                {children}
            </dialog>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DialogModal;
```

And the problem is that when I click on `browse` button, the modal is closed. I would like to close the modal only when indeed, click outside it. What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

The problem i see is that the `onClick` handler on the dialog element, its checking if the click is inside the dialog and if not, its calling the `onClose` function, closing the modal.

Instead of using the `onClick` on the dialog element, you can use it on the `modal-overlay div` class.

```
const DialogModal = ({ isOpened, onClose, children }: Props) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isOpened) {
            ref.current?.showModal();
            document.body.classList.add("modal-open"); // prevent bg scroll
        } else {
            ref.current?.close();
            document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
        }
    }, [isOpened]);

    return (
        <div
            className="modal-overlay"
            onClick={(e) =>
                ref.current && !isClickInsideRectangle(e, ref.current) && onClose()
            }
        >
            <dialog className="modal-dialog" ref={ref} onCancel={onClose}>
                {children}
            </dialog>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**Updated Approach**:

```
const DialogModal = ({ isOpened, onClose, children }: Props) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isOpened) {
            ref.current?.showModal();
            document.body.classList.add("modal-open"); // prevent bg scroll
        } else {
            ref.current?.close();
            document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
        }
    }, [isOpened]);

    const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target as Node)) {
            onClose();
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="modal-overlay" onClick={handleClick}>
            <dialog className="modal-dialog" ref={ref} onCancel={onClose}>
                {children}
            </dialog>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Hmm it still doesnt work

Comment: Any specific error or can you console log?

Comment: There is no errors, I updated my code in the question

Comment: now the problem is that click outisde doesnt close the modal (because of the dialog tag which has auto margin) and when I click browse and the window open, the modal is still shown but when I click cancel, it's being closed.

Comment: With previo appraoach (rectangle), I debugged clicking on the `browse` button and it turns out the the target there was an input but with all the positions 0 which cause the modal to be closed.